# NavBar from Template from bootswatch has a space on top

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm a beginner learning asp.net and c# from udemy course, but there's a problem on my template, has a space on top of Navigation bar, I dont know why, and how to remove it. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ozaKI.png)

Comment: Could you please indicate the place in the screenshot where the space is happening to make it easier to follow where the issue is? 

Also add the CSS you are using on the navbar element or body, so we can try to help you with that. (Note giving a name to the image helps as well).

Comment: Please share your _Layout.cshtml file. If you have a separate view for your NavBar, please share that as well. Also, if your new to ASP.NET MVC, I would recommend starting with ASP.NET Core MVC instead of regular ASP.NET MVC which runs on .NET Framework.